# Scalar sql function with 3 parameters in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have written this function in SQL

```
alter function TVprest (@emitente int, @mes int, @ano int)
returns float  
as
begin 
    declare @tcu float;

    select @tcu = sum(cast(vtprest as money)) 
    from ctrc 
    where emitente = @emitente  and MONTH (EMISSAODATA ) = @mes 
      and YEAR (EMISSAODATA)=@ano and status = 'A'

    if (@tcu is null)
        set @tcu = 0;

    return @tcu  
end
```

And trying to call the same function in C# with this code:

```
public double TVprest (int emitente, int mess, int anno)
{
        double saida;
        SqlConnection abre1 = Tconex.GetConnection();
        SqlDataAdapter da3 = new SqlDataAdapter();

        if (abre1.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { abre1.Open(); }

        SqlParameter emit = new SqlParameter("@emitente", SqlDbType.Int);
        emit.Value = emitente;

        SqlParameter mes = new SqlParameter("@mes", SqlDbType.Int);
        mes.Value = mess;

        SqlParameter ano = new SqlParameter("@ano", SqlDbType.Int);
        ano.Value = ano;

        SqlCommand TotalF = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.Tcupom(@emitente,@mes,@ano),", abre1);
        TotalF.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        saida = Convert.ToDouble(TotalF.ExecuteScalar());
        return saida;
    }
```

When run I get this error :

> Failed to convert parameter value from SqlParameter to an Int32

What is wrong? Calling the function with these parameters :

```
    double Tvprest = impx.TVprest(504, 5, 2013);
    lblVtprest.Text = Tvprest.ToString();
```

Comment: btw; you see to be assigning `ano.Value = ano;` - should that be `= anno` ?

Comment: Wait a minute. Your C# doesn't appear to be calling the stored procedure at all. How is the stored procedure relevant here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't added the parameters to your command

```
SqlCommand TotalF = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.Tcupom(@emitente,@mes,@ano),", abre1);
TotalF.Parameters.Add(emit);
TotalF.Parameters.Add(mes);
TotalF.Parameters.Add(ano);
saida = Convert.ToDouble(TotalF.ExecuteScalar());
```

However, I think you are missing to explain something in your question. You have a function called TVprest but you call a `SELECT dbo.Tcupom`. Not clear what is that `Tcupom`

Comment: just in terms of convenience and code simplicity: `TotalF.Parameters.AddWithValue("emitente", emitente); TotalF.Parameters.AddWithValue("mes", mess); TotalF.Parameters.AddWithValue("ano", anno);` etc

Comment: Sorry i have forget the parameters , but now i have another problem

Comment: And what is this new problem?

Comment: @Steve shhh... It is a secret!

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental error here is, as Steve rightly notes, not adding the parameters correctly. However, as a general code-error-avoidance trick, you might want to try tools like [dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper) which make it much harder to get it wrong. For example:

```
return abre1.Query<double>("SELECT dbo.Tcupom(@emitente,@mess,@anno)",
     new { emitente, mess, anno }).Single();
```

That does *everything* here, but it gets it right, and is easy to read. It even works with your more complex types, i.e.

```
string region = ...
var customers = connection.Query<Customer>(
       "select * from Customers where Region = @region",
       new { region }).ToList();
```